# Partial model entity classes resets after updating model from database in ASP.NET, Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have some data annotations in the entity partial classes for my model in a ASP.NET MVC web application solution.

When I make changes to the database from SQL Server and update the model (.edmx) from database it resets all the entity classes. So all my custom data annotations are removed.

How can I make sure this doesn't happen and updates only changes made to the entity and database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never directly modify auto-generated code if you can avoid it for this very reason.  The reason that those entity classes are declared partial is specifically so that you can create other parts.

Create a separate code file and declare another partial class for the entities that you need to annotate.  Add the attributes to your own partial classes and then they will be unaffected by any changes made to the auto-generated code by a designer or wizard.

Put all your code files in a separate folder and they can have the same names as the originals.  Just make sure that you get the namespace right.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes makes sense. So can I add a folder to Model folder and have the same name partial classes?

Comment: Yes.  I am working on a project that uses a database first approach, and includes partial classes that contain additional...things...in them.  Each time we make a model change, the POCO classes are re-created, but our partial classes remain untouched.

Comment: Ok do I need to have the custom partial classes to contain exactly same lines as the auto generated partial classes? Can I only add the attributes in the custom partial classes and not virtual objects? I'm adding the custom partial classes to a subfolder in the Model folder.

Comment: You add additional properties / methods in your partial class.  The folder structure doesn't matter (personal preference as to how you are organising your solution) but the namespace does matter.

Comment: These partial classes are part of the class.  The class already contains the auto-generated properties and such so why would you add them again to the same class?  These partial classes exist solely for you to annotate so that's all you do.  If you want to add more properties and such then you can but I wouldn't expect that you would in this case.  When compiled, the multiple parts are treated as one class, so you get the properties from one part and the attributes from the other.

Comment: Great, should read more about the OO concepts for C#. Now for source control with SVN do I have to commit these auto generated partial classes? Not sure since I will have same named .cs files in separate sub directories. Also would I check in .tt files and .edmx files. Not sure what to commit with a database first approach project since some files are autogenerated.

Comment: We check it all in at my office.  Not sure if there are some parts that you could omit but having it all under source control causes no issues that I've ever seen.